# Ruby Variable coming back with [["variable"]]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to test getting a variable from mysql using ruby however when I get the variable and display it in the console using puts it reads variable with no quotations etc however when I attempt to call the variable elsewhere eg `username = "#{dev_test1}"` I get an output like this `[["variable called from database"]]` I just want to get a variable I can use in a string that doesn't haven `[[""]]` in it. The code I am using is below

```
require "mysql2"

    client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "", :database =>"test")
    test_query1 = client.query("SELECT test1 FROM accounts LIMIT 1").each(:as => :array)
    dev_test1 = test_query1.each { | row | }
    puts dev_test1
    test_query2 = client.query("SELECT test2 FROM accounts LIMIT 1").each(:as => :array)
    dev_test2 = test_query2.each { | row | }
    puts dev_test2
    username = "#{dev_test1}"
    password = "#{dev_test2}"
    puts username
    puts password
```

Comment: Try removing the `.each(:as => :array)`. This is useless because you're not using a block with it. Also, you're not doing anything with the blocks with `|row|`. You may want to read up on blocks in Ruby.

Comment: It is a little unusual to be using `Mysql2::Client` directly. Do you really need to be working this low-level? [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) is really simple and makes interfacing with databases a lot less messy.

Comment: @tadman - Sequel or not, first thing is to use ORM, especially that the question is tagged with RoR. @David_Hogan - have you tried `account = Account.first; puts account.test1`?

Comment: Thanks for all your responses @MarkThomas

Comment: Thank you guys for all your responses, I'm going to try look into Sequel when I get abit better with low level stuff as Im learning from the ground up, I tired your suggestion Mark but it caused terminal to spit out random numbers :L the answer I got seems to be pointing me in the right direction :D

Comment: "From the ground up" is like trying to learn how to drive by building a car out of parts in the scrapyard. Ruby on Rails is a great place to start, a more top-down approach, where it shows you by example. When you're more comfortable you can dig deeper by degrees, eventually writing your own queries from scratch *when necessary*. You could spend years learning about SQL without having much to show for it, or you could spend weeks learning Rails and seeing how it approaches problems, developing your own improvements on the defaults over time.

Comment: [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) can be a lot to absorb, but it's a *lot* less than having to learn RDBMS fundamentals from first principles. Once you know what ActiveRecord is doing and you want to know more, keep digging down through the abstraction layer. In my experience, 95% of the time ActiveRecord will do the job, 5% of the time you'll need to get creative or work around it, but that's okay. It's easy to do that when necessary: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` gives you access to very low-level data access methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of things that could be cleaned up in your code, but I'll look at why you are getting two different answers in the terminal and in your actual code.
In Ruby, `puts` and `#{variable}` are not the same thing.  `puts` will actually alter the value to be a readable string by stripping out the array, if it is passed an array. This removes the brackets.

String interpolation (`#{variable}`) is the equivalent of calling `.to_s` on your variable. This will convert the array to a string with the brackets intact.  So by the time you call puts, password has been saved as a string, so puts will display it as is, brackets and all.

So

```
password = "#{array}" #==> "[[array_contents]]"
puts password  #==> "[[array_contents]]"
```

Whereas

```
puts array  #==> "array_contents"
```

Comment: Thats excatly the kind of answer I needed I apologise for the crappy code however I'm trying to learn ruby at the moment, how would I strip the array_contents using #{array}, Thank you in advance @Kenneye

Comment: `password = array[0]` would do it, or in other words: *set password to be the 0th element of `array`*. Your version was `password = "#{array}"` which is *set password to be a string containing the string version of `array`*, and is equivalent to `password = array.to_s`.

Comment: @tadman is correct, but you may need `password = array[0][0]` since it is an array nested in another array.  One way to guarantee you get all of the brackets gone would be `password = array.join('')`.  This joins all of the entries into a string, seperated by an empty string ('').

Comment: To be clearer, the end result would be:
`password = dev_test2.join("")`